# Capturing frames from webcam using DirectShow.NET

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, directshow.net

I am new at DirectShow, so some parts of this library i don't understand well.
I already see the example DxSnap, but i need to *capture frames without previewing it*, for futher processing. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could build one yourself. If you look into the windows sdk 7.0~ folders you can go to samples > multimedia > directshow > and there should be a filters folder that shows you how to make generic filters and do w/e you want

Comment: but what if i will get images from still pin of camera? The problem is that there is a window with the video previewing pop ups when i start the capture graph.

Comment: if you use Video Renderer, that will create a window popup. Im confused as to whether you want to capture to a file or capture to a program. if you want to capture to a file you can do Camera -> Smart Tee -> AVI Mux -> File Writer.    if you want to capture to a program/code, you would have to create a filter and capture the image in the filter

Answer (score 12):

If your main concern is "access webcam" and not "access webcam with DirectShow", then I would have a look at the [AForge.NET-Framework](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/). I tried it with DirectShow once just to find out that I could do the same thing with multiple video sources in less time with less code.

Here is some sample code: [Access to USB cameras and video files using DirectShow](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/directshow_video.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i must do it with directshow. I hear a lot about AForge Framework, but my customer whants to do it with DirectShow.NET =(

Comment: Well, I guess it boils down to DirectShow in the end, so AForge would just simplify the process. But that's what you get when dealing with customers :-)

Comment: FYI, AForge.NET is good for video only (does not capture audio...)

Comment: @itsho shame I spent a week on a project to figure out that this library limits me to capture audio as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Construct a Windows Form as shown in the picture.

[Click this link to see how the WinForm looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHBP.png)

- The WinForm itself is named **Form1**
- "Recording ..." label is named **lblRecording**
- ComboBox is named **cbCameraDevices**
- "Stop" button name is **button1**
- "Copy" button name is **button2**
- "Start" button name is **btnStartVideo**
- There is also a pictureBox named **pictureBox1** in which video image will be shown.

These names let us associate the event handlers (code below) with the respective control.

If the program is built successfully and run, use the **combobox** to select an available source. Click "**Start**" to see video feed. Click "**Copy**" to clone the image onto the clipboard. Click "**Stop**" to close the image feed.

The code was tested using Microsoft:

- Windows 10 - X64 (Intel machine)
- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- .NET Framework 4.5.

To build the code, the project containing this code needs to have these **References**:

- AForge.Video.DirectShow
- AForge.Video
- AForge

The packages can be pulled into the project by NuGet. In Visual Studio IDE:

1. Tools ->
2. NuGet Package Manager ->
3. Manage NuGet Package for Solution...

Search for "AForge" and install the respective packages.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CameraDevice;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Threading;

namespace CameraCaptureTest3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CameraImaging camImg;
        bool StopVideo = true;
        Thread thrVideo;
        object mImageLock;
        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            camImg = new CameraImaging();
            mImageLock = new object();
            // enumerate video devices
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            cbCameraDevices.Items.Clear();
            foreach(FilterInfo i in videoDevices) cbCameraDevices.Items.Add(i.Name);
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        // VideoRecordin() is meant to be run on a separate thread
        //---------------------------------------------------------            
        private void VideoRecording()
        {
            camImg.videoSource.Start();

            while (!StopVideo)
            {
                lock (mImageLock)
                {
                    Bitmap tmp = (Bitmap)camImg.bitmap.Clone();

                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                        {
                            pictureBox1.Image = tmp;
                            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = tmp;
                        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(33);
            }
            camImg.videoSource.Stop();
        }

        private void btnStartVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopVideo = false;
            try
            {
                camImg.videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(camImg.videoDevices[cbCameraDevices.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                thrVideo = new Thread(VideoRecording);
                thrVideo.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                lblRecording.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No camera is chosen.", "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            StopVideo = true;
            if (thrVideo != null) thrVideo.Join();
            lblRecording.Visible = false;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopVideo = true;
            if (thrVideo != null)
                while (thrVideo.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                    Application.DoEvents();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            lblRecording.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name for CameraImaging is not found and I didn't manage to find it.